# Normalisation to 3nf and functional dependencies two

Tags: mysql, sql, database-normalization

I need to identify functional dependenciers and normalise the following tables to 3NF. I'm still unclear of all dependencies.

If I have dependencies do I push them into other tables?

Video store

**Customer table**

```
customerNo | customername | address | phone | numberofbooking
```

- Customer Number – The unique number related to a customer.
- Customer Name – The name of the customer.
- Address – The customers address.
- Phone – Phone number of the customer.
- Number Of Rentals – Current number of rentals customer has.

`customerno` is my primary key, everything except `numberofbooking` is dependent on `customerno`?

**video table**

```
SerielNo | CopyNumber | title | yearmade | director | origen
```

- SerialCode – Unique serial code at the back of a DVD.
- CopyNumber - the copy number of that video. For instance a video could havmultiple copies in store, this is used to distinguish between each copy.
- Title – The name of the movie.
- Year Made – The year hte movie was published.
- Director – The director of the movie.
- Origin – The country in which the movie was made.

As `serielno` is not unique I was or copy number I was goint to add a `videoId` unique to each video as a serial number can have many copies.

**rentals table**

```
title | customerName
```

- title – The video name that has been rented.
- customername – The name of the customer that has rented the movie.

Not sure what to do here.

Comment: Forget about the rentals for the moment. I am missng material/title -> edition -> medium -> copy/instance. Next: what do I rent, a title or a copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove the NumberOfBooking field from the customer table. This is redundant, and can easily be calculated from the rentals table.
- Consider splitting the video table into two tables, where one contains the information of a unique video, and the other contains information about the copies of each video.
- Consider adding an id to identify the video copies, this is easier to use than a combination of serial number and video copy number.
- Consider adding a director table, as some directors will have made several videos.
- Consider adding a country table, as many videos will come from the same country.
- Use the customer number in the rentals table, not the customer name. The customer name might not be unique.
- Use the identity of the video copy in the rentals table, not the video title.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have listed I would...

- remove the `numberOfBooking` column (This can be calculated cleanly with a subquery from the `rentals` table later.)
- `Director` should probably be its own table and then create a foreign key reference from `Video` if that relationship is required.
- replace the `customerName` column on the rentals table with a foreign key reference to the customers table.

Good luck!